# WordPress | Post Query | Query on post categories to create sub-category filter and applying it to an Ajax filter in my function file

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm struggling to get my portfolio page's filter to work. I have quite a good knowledge of WordPress and cannot seem to...

Aims:

- Create a filter with only the categories that are a subcategory of a specified category.
- Use the selected option from the sub-category filter to Ajax the relevant posts for the chosen filter into view.

So onto the relevant code:

My portfolio page that successfully pulls the posts from my portfolio category:

```
<div class="portfolio-filters">

    <?php
    $filtercategory = get_template_directory() . "/template-parts/category-filter.php";
    include_once($filtercategory);
    ?>

</div>

<div class="portfolio-pieces">

    <div class="portfolio-pieces-inner">

        <div id="response">

            <!-- DEFAULT PORTFOLIO PAGE DISPLAY -->
            <?php
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'category_name' => 'portfolio',
                'posts_per_page' => '-1',
                'orderby' => 'post_date',
                'order' => 'DESC'
            ); ?>

            <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

            <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>

                <div class="portfolio-piece" <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>style="background-image: url(<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>);"<?php endif; ?>>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="box-link" target="_blank"></a>

                    <div class="portfolio-piece-hover">

                    </div>

                    <div class="portfolio-piece-inner">
                        <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <?php
                endwhile;
                wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

In the snippet above, I call my filter file. Create the response area and load in the complete list of portfolio pieces.

My Category Filter file looks like this:

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="POST" id="filter">
    <?php
        $args = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'category_name' => 'portfolio-category',
            'orderby' => 'name',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'parent' => 0
        ); 
        if( $terms = get_terms( $args ) ) :
            echo '<select name="categoryfilter"><option>Select category...</option>';
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
            echo '<option value="' . $term->term_id . '">' . $term->name . '</option>';
        endforeach;
            echo '</select>';
        endif;
    ?>

    <button>Apply filters</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="customfilter">
</form>

<script>
    jQuery(function($) {
        $('#filter').submit(function(){
            var filter = $('#filter');
            $.ajax({
                url:filter.attr('action'),
                data:filter.serialize(), // form data
                type:filter.attr('method'), // POST
                beforeSend:function(xhr){
                    filter.find('button').text('Applying Filters...');
                },
                success:function(data){
                    filter.find('button').text('Apply filters');
                    $('#response').html(data);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Where the above snippet is 'attempting' to create a form with an action that points to the admin-ajax.php file in my wp-admin folder (it is there).

Then loops through my get_terms args to present the sub-categories I wish into a drop-down list, with an apply button.

The last snippet handles it all. Changing the text of the button depending on its state and gives my response div as the return place.

My functions file is like this:

```
/* Filter Post Results */
function catfilter_filter_function(){
    $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'date', // we will sort posts by date
        'order' => $_POST['date'] // ASC or DESC
    );

    // for taxonomies / categories
    if( isset( $_POST['categoryfilter'] ) )
        $args['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $_POST['categoryfilter']
            )
        );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if( $query->have_posts() ) :
        while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();

            echo "<div class=\"portfolio-piece\" style=\"background-image: url(" . get_the_post_thumbnail_url() . ");\">";

                echo "<a href=\"" . the_permalink() . "\" class=\"box-link\" target=\"_blank\"></a>";

                echo "<div class=\"portfolio-piece-hover\">";

                echo "</div>";

                echo "<div class=\"portfolio-piece-inner\">";

                    echo "<h4>" . the_title() . "</h4>";

                echo "</div>";

            echo "</div>";

        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    else :
        echo 'No posts found';
    endif;

    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_customfilter', 'catfilter_filter_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_customfilter', 'catfilter_filter_function');
/* END Filter Post Results */
```

The functions file script works will pull the posts stated in the filter through.

**Can someone please help me narrow down my category filter to only have the relevant sub-categories in it? - They are sub-categories of the 'Portfolio Categories' category that has the slug 'portfolio-category'**

I am able to show the complete list of categories, or just the base parent categories, not the subcategories...

My categories are set up like this:

```
— Portfolio Piece

— — Portfolio Category

— — — Automation

— — — Design

— — — Digital

— — — Exhibitions

— — — PR / Social

— — — Strategy

— — — Tech Insights

— — Sector

— — — Construction

— — — Manufacturing

— — — Oil & Gas

— — — Science
```

I have had no joke 50+ attempts at different articles and cannot for the life of me narrow this list down.

So massive thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are able to specify the parent for which the get_terms should iterate through by using:

```
parent => cat_ID
```

Where cat_ID is the ID of the category.

You can find out the category ID by hovering over the link to the category in the category list, then checking the URL you will be directed to in the link note in the bottom left of your browser.